# Masters database not replicating on slave after restarting client

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm trying to implement master slave replication and It's works fine with no errors, database is replicated on slave, but when I close my servers and open them again and add something in masters database it's not replicated in slave , do I have to follow these steps every time I start my server?

Setup on Masters server

```
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl_user'@'192.168.1.20'    
IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql> use mydb;
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
mysql> exit;
```

my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog-do-db=mydb
server-id=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
```

in terminal again

```
# service mysqld restart

mysql > SHOW MASTER STATUS;

# mysqldump -u root -p mydb > mydb.sql
# scp mydb.sql 192.168.1.20:/opt/
```

SETUP SLAVE 2 SERVER

```
 # vim /etc/my.cnf
 [mysqld]
 server-id=2
 replicate-do-db=mydb

 # /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
 # mysql -u root -p mydb < mydb.sql

 mysql>  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.10',
-> MASTER_USER='repl_user',
-> MASTER_PASSWORD='secretpassword',
-> MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002',
-> MASTER_LOG_POS=107;

mysql> SLAVE START;
mysql> show slave status \G
```

Also it's is only replicating one database by dumping one database on slave server

```
 # mysqldump -u root -p mydb > mydb.sql
```

How can I dump all the databases from masters to slave server?

[image]

Comment: What does "close my servers" mean?

Comment: I'm using putty! and with that two different servers what I meant is when I close down the putty / terminals

Comment: That won't stop mysqld (the server), only mysql (the client).

Comment: yes sorry mys mistake! but when i close the client and open it again the replication isn't working anymore , it just shows "waiting for master to send event"

Comment: waiting for master to send event is usually a very good sign. Have you tried testing your replicaton by making modifications to the data on the master?

Comment: yes my replication works fine the first time I try the above mentioned procedure! it replicate databases and data but when I close both clients and start them again the connection is lost and there is no more replication

Comment: How do you start your clients again?  a client is not something you start like a service.

Comment: I;m working in putty on two different terminals one is master and the other is slave. I open it normally by clicking on the putty icon and then start mysql by mysql -uroot and then I create a new database in master and bam it;s not replicating in slave. (My master and slave mysql versions are different)

Comment: What are the versions?  What does the Slave say for `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`?

Comment: Terminology:  `putty` and `mysql` are not run as a "service".  `mysqld` is run as a "service".

Comment: Master is 5.6.28 and Slave is 5.5.47. 
 
sometimes the IO is yes but above it is, waiting for master to send event ,and sometimes IO is no and above is Connecting to master.

Comment: Do I have to run change master to master every time I start ? because apparently it worked I changed the file position from master status to the commands i executed in slave and it apparently worked only on the database I created when I configured the replication.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the slave from a copy of the master. So take a full dump of the master:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --single-transaction --master-data=2 > fulldump.sql
```

Restore the dump file on the slave server, reset slave and then execute CHANGE MASTER again. Make sure to remove replicate-do-db or any replication filters on slave my.cnf.

Comment: #  mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --master-data > /root/dbdump.db       will this line work as well? and why do we have to remove replicate-do-db? shouldn't we add all the databases in cnf file? Isn't it necessary to specify each database name in master my.cnf file to do replication?

Comment: and what about losing connection when I close servers and then start it again?

Comment: @MIC using --master-data should work as well. if you don't require replication filtering just leave out replicate-do-db or replicate-wild-* variables. no need to add all databases on cnf file or specify each db name in the master's cnf file.

Comment: @MIC if you just exit from the mysql client or close putty it does not stop replication, however, if you execute 'stop slave' on the slave server before exiting then that will of course stop replication

Comment: no replication stops when i close putty! and I didn;t execute stop slave before executing

Comment: @MIC what does 'show slave status\G' output say? if slave SQL and IO is running (yes) then replication is working. i wonder what your exact commands are just before exiting putty or after reconnecting to the servers.

Comment: sometimes the IO is yes but above it, is waiting for master to send event and sometimes IO is no and above is Connecting to master. There are no exact commands I just shut it down. my master and slave mysql versions are different can it be the cause of all this?

Comment: @MIC master should be lower version than slave. you have it all wrong. mysql supports when master is 5.5 and slave is 5.6. that is why sometimes you see replication broken when you log in...

Comment: but it's clearly stated in documentation that both master and slave should have the same version. I re installed mysql 5.5.46 version on both master and slave. Anyway my replication is working fine for now :)

Comment: @MIC yes aside from having the same version in master and slave mysql also supports when master is of older version than in slave but not the other way around